# Access compilation element in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-1.1

I want to be able to determine if the web.config element

```
  <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="false" />
```

if the property is debug is set to true or false.

```
Public Shared Function isDebug() as Boolean
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
End sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for showing me the answer